# worry about travelling with 2 passports with different Names (different names in ticket and passport)

Tags: tickets, dual-nationality, passport-stamps

- Now I am in A country (Iran).
- My ticket was issued and the boarding pass will be
  issued through B passport.
- C country Does Not need a visa with B passport

I do not want immigration to stamp my B passport, but I must prove who I am and it means I must show my A passport (they see both the boarding pass and passport).

The question: 
Is it possible to show B passport to prove matching the passport and boarding pass, but they stamp my A passport to exit?

In return (entering A country I won't have a problem because will not be any boarding pass to show immigration.

Comment: This depends largely on whether the government officers stamping your passport will also want to see your boarding pass, and, if so, *on that country's laws and regulations.*  What country is A?

Comment: They see Passport and Boarding pass. A= Iran

Comment: Hm.  It sounds potentially tricky, from what little I know about Iranian law and politics.  Unfortunately I cannot read the Arabic script, much less Farsi, so I don't have an easy way of looking for information about it.  If you find some information elsewhere, please do post an answer here.

Comment: The actual information out of the comments is edited into the question, but there are parts there that give a partial answer and those are not to be deleted yet.